# fav button in collectionView Cell

Tags: swift

I have a fav button in Cell. I have defined different images according to this fav button, DAVMEDIAfileId. If Fav is selected and if not. But at the moment, all the values ​​in the DAVMEDIAfileId array are either true or false. I just want it to change one value. Since it all changes, it doesn't work. I just want the fav button to change the value of the selected DAVMEDIAfileId [indexPath.row]

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "davetiyeGosterCell", for: indexPath) as! davetiyeCell
    cell.favCell.isSelected = !cell.favCell.isSelected
    let key = "\(DAVMEDIAfileId[indexPath.row])"
    let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    userDefault.set(cell.favCell.isSelected, forKey: key)
    userDefault.synchronize()

    let keygetir = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "\(DAVMEDIAfileId[indexPath.row])")

    if keygetir == true {
                cell.favCell.setImage(UIImage(named: "heart"), for: .normal)
                cell.favCell.setImageTintColor(UIColor.black)
                cell.favCell.setImage(UIImage(named: "heart"), for: .selected)
                cell.favCell.setImageTintColor(UIColor.red)
    }

    if keygetir == false {
                cell.favCell.setImage(UIImage(named: "heart"), for: .normal)
                cell.favCell.setImageTintColor(UIColor.red)
                cell.favCell.setImage(UIImage(named: "heart"), for: .selected)
                cell.favCell.setImageTintColor(UIColor.black)
    }
 }
```

Comment: please elaborate your question ... what you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "davetiyeGosterCell", for: indexPath) as! davetiyeCell
    let selected = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "keyIndex_\(DAVMEDIAfileId[indexPath.row])")
    cell.favCell.isSelected =  selected
    cell.favCell.setImage(UIImage(named: "heart"), for: .normal) // I think, you should use empty heart
    cell.favCell.setImage(UIImage(named: "heart"), for: .selected)
    cell.favCell.tintColor = selected ? .red : .black

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "davetiyeGosterCell", for: indexPath) as! davetiyeCell
    let selected = !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "keyIndex_\(DAVMEDIAfileId[indexPath.row])")
    cell.favCell.isSelected =  selected
    cell.favCell.tintColor = selected ? .red : .black

    let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    userDefault.set(selected, forKey: "keyIndex_\(DAVMEDIAfileId[indexPath.row])")
    userDefault.synchronize()
}
```